# How can I see Office 2019 for Mac product key

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-office, product-key, microsoft-office-2019

We use a shared account that has 25 licenses associated to it.

When we install Office 2019 on a Mac and activate it by signing in with the shared account it lists all licensed products but not the product keys, the list is all same like "Office Home & Business 2019" repeated 25 times. And when we select one randomly, actually we associate a product key on the computer but this information is not listed [online](https://account.microsoft.com/services) or on the Office application's help screens.

Microsoft has a [document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-multiple-one-time-purchase-office-installs-that-use-the-same-microsoft-account-b2897d43-9ec1-4040-9cf0-2bafa416e071) that recommends saving which product key is used on which computer and it guides the customer how to look up the product key on Windows but not on macOS.

We'd like to know how we accomplish that on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Per their support, this is not possible per Microsoft, as it's too technically difficult to figure out. There is no timeline as a future feature request.

Answer (score -1):

I am afraid we could not find the Office key for some security reasons.

Here is an article "[Using product keys with Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-product-keys-with-office-12a5763a-d45c-4685-8c95-a44500213759)", it lists some questions about "View your product key".

It's best to [contact Microsoft for help](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/contactus/).

Comment: On Windows it can retrieve at least last 5 characters so on macOS I expect to have this too.

And I've tried chat support but no luck, they have no knowledge on this.

Comment: On some documents it says; on license selection screen that lists product name it shows last characters of product key of that record but It does not show at least on macOS. If it was like that then the issue has been solved for us but It is not like that anymore.